# SVG renders as a square when converted to a font using svgicons2svgfont

Tags: svg, fonts

I have a problem when trying to convert an svg into a font with svgicons2svgfont

I've tried formatting the svg so many times. All the other icons work perfectly. I have no clue what is going on.

Here is the SVG

```
<svg width="14" height="14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g opacity=".8" clip-path="url(#a)">
<path d="M9.112 6.885a2.084 2.084 0 1 1-4.167-.001 2.084 2.084 0 0 1 4.167.001Z" fill="#0B2343"/>
<path d="M10.998 6.9h2.571M.5 6.9h2.57M7.035 2.936V.366M7.035 13.434v-2.57M9.92 4.01l1.817-1.818M2.332 11.603l1.817-1.817M9.92 9.786l1.817 1.817M2.332 2.192 4.149 4.01" stroke="#0B2343" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</g>
<defs>
<clipPath id="a"><path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h14v14H0z"/></clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>
```

It will be amazing if you can help me to find what is causing this!

Thanks

Comment: From the [documentation](https://github.com/nfroidure/svgicons2svgfont) it doesn't seem like this library supports clipPath elements. You're probably better off recreating the icon from scratch in something like Inkscape such that it only uses elements that the library supports.

Comment: Hi Robert. Thanks for the information regarding the clipPath. That was the problem.

I've formatted the svg with https://www.svgviewer.dev/ and now works like a charm.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the suggestion of Robert, I could solve the issue:

1. Manually remove the `clipPath` element.
2. using `svgviewer.dev` to format the svg

This was the final result and now it renders properly.

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 14 14" style="enable-background:new 0 0 14 14" xml:space="preserve">
  <path class="st0" d="M9.078 6.985a2.084 2.084 0 1 1-4.167-.001 2.084 2.084 0 0 1 4.167.001zM13.534 7.5h-2.57a.5.5 0 1 1 0-1h2.57a.5.5 0 1 1 0 1zM3.036 7.5H.466a.5.5 0 1 1 0-1h2.57a.5.5 0 1 1 0 1zM7 3.536a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V.466a.5.5 0 1 1 1 0v2.57a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5zM7 14.034a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-2.57a.5.5 0 1 1 1 0v2.57a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5zM9.886 4.61a.498.498 0 0 1-.354-.854l1.818-1.817a.5.5 0 1 1 .707.707l-1.818 1.817a.498.498 0 0 1-.353.146zM2.298 12.202a.498.498 0 0 1-.354-.853L3.761 9.53a.5.5 0 1 1 .707.708l-1.817 1.817a.498.498 0 0 1-.353.146zM11.703 12.202a.498.498 0 0 1-.353-.146l-1.818-1.817a.5.5 0 1 1 .707-.708l1.818 1.818a.5.5 0 0 1-.354.853zM4.115 4.61a.498.498 0 0 1-.354-.147L1.944 2.646a.5.5 0 1 1 .707-.707l1.817 1.817a.5.5 0 0 1-.353.853z"/>
</svg>
```

Thanks!